# Bash script - working with long filename

Tags: bash

Converted all my CDs into flac (for storage) but made the mistake of using a long filename (Artist Name- Album Name - Song Title).

Sample filename: 
**Jennifer Warnes - Famous Blue Raincoat - Ain't No Cure For Love.flac**

Wanted to convert all the flac to mp3 (for mp3 player) using the following bash script. But first have to convert them to wav (before converting to mp3)

In bash ran :

```
for i in *.flac; do
  flac -d $i;
done
```

This simple script works on filename like **famous_blue_raincoat.flac**

However, due to space between the letters (and probably also the '), the scripts just wouldn't work on filenames like: 
**Jennifer Warnes - Famous Blue Raincoat - Ain't No Cure For Love.flac**

Any recommendations and advise welcomed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need quotes :

```
 for i in *.flac; do flac -d "$i"; done
```

This behaviour is called [word splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting)